# Linear Transformation representation matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

I have some linear algebra question regarding

let $\left(\vec{v_{1}},\vec{v_{2},}\vec{v_{3}}\right)$
 be a base for$ \mathbb{R}^{3}$
  and$ \left(\vec{w_{1}}\vec{w_{2}}\right)$
  be a base for$ \mathbb{R}^{2}$

$u_{1}=\vec{v_{2}}+\vec{v_{3}}
 ; u_{2}=\vec{v_{1}}+\vec{v_{3}}
  ; u_{3}=\vec{v_{1}}+\vec{v_{2}}$

$z_{1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(w_{1}+w_{2}\right)
  ; z_{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(w_{1}-w_{2}\right)$

I have proven that$ \vec{u_{1}},\vec{u_{2}},\vec{u_{3}}$
 and $\vec{z_{1}},\vec{z_{2}}$
  are bases for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$
 and $\mathbb{R}^{2}$
 respectively.

I tried to make a linear combination of a$\vec{u_{1}}+b\vec{u_{2}}+c\vec{u_{3}}=0$
  and reached that$ a,b,c=0$
  same for the other 2.

**Now the part where I have a doubt:**

let linear transformation $T:
 \mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$
  be given.

The representation matrix with respect to $\left(\vec{v_{1}},\vec{v_{2},}\vec{v_{3}}\right)$
 and $\left(\vec{w_{1}}\vec{w_{2}}\right)$
 is A
  :

$A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 & 1\\
3 & 2 & -3
\end{bmatrix}$

find the representation matrix B
  with respect to $\vec{u_{1}},\vec{u_{2}},\vec{u_{3}}$
  and $\vec{w_{1}}\vec{w_{2}}$

Basically $A=\left[T\right]_{w}^{v}$
  such that $A=\begin{bmatrix}\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\left[T(v_{1})\right]_{w} & \left[T(v_{3})\right]_{w} & \left[T(v_{2})\right]_{w}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{bmatrix}$

**Also I know that** $T(\vec{u}_{1})=T(\vec{v_{2}}+\vec{v_{3}})=T(\vec{v_{2}})+T(\vec{v_{3}})$

and then $\left[T(\vec{u_{1}})\right]_{w}
 =\left[T(\vec{v_{2}})+T(\vec{v_{3}})\right]_{w}$

**Can I split this into** $\left[T(\vec{v_{2}})+T(\vec{v_{3}})\right]_{w}=\left[T(\vec{v_{2}})\right]_{w}+\left[T(\vec{v_{3}})\right]_{w}$
  is it something legitimate to do ? if yes please could you explain ?

Comment: What is $z_3$ ?

Comment: sorry, typo, it is $z_2$

Comment: yes you can do that. the base change itself is again a linear transformation

Comment: What do you mean by saying that the "base changes itself"? could you please elaborate ?

Comment: You want $\left[T(\vec{v_{2}})+T(\vec{v_{3}})\right]_{w}$, which is $T(\vec{v_{2}})+T(\vec{v_{3}})$ expressed in the new basis of $w$ (a change of base), you can express this as a matrix (since it is a linear transformation) and then use the distributive axiom (you need to add an @ before any username if you want to address this user)

Comment: second one is not a basis

Comment: @user190080 Thank you!! so basically you are saying that expressing $T(\vec{v_{2}})$ as $\left[T(\vec{v_{2}})\right]$ is another linear transformation which has the additive and homogeneous properties ?

Comment: @Mambo it became right now I had a typo, sorry :)

Comment: If you find the change of basis matrix from $u$ to $v$, call it $T$, and the change of basis matrix from $w$ to $z$, call it $S$. Then $B = SAT$.

Comment: @user313448 yes! it is an isomorphism, so just think of it as multiplying a matrix from the left (ofc you can also compute this matrix)